# Exception while getting the source code of a webpage

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

I have tried both of the following methods to get the source code of a webpage and neither were able to open the webpage. Both methods through the exception remote sever 403 forbidden

```
string htmlstring = String.Empty;    
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
htmlstring = wc.DownloadString(website);
```

and

```
string htmlstring = String.Empty;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(website);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dt = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dt);
htmlstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Both codes should work fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Both are fine in a general sense, you need to state how it fails.  Familiarise yourself with Fiddler and compare working browser requests with failing request made in C#.

Comment: both throw an exception

Comment: Including the full content of the exception in your question would be helpful.

Comment: Then you need to show the full exception thats thrown, including the accompanying stack trace

Comment: Edit your question, include the `Exception` type, stack trace and so on. 
Also please take a look at how to write an [mcve]

Comment: remote server 403 Forbidden

Comment: Can you access the site in any browser? 403 is an error because you're not authenticated, you won't be able to fix that if you don't have credeantials.

Comment: That means you dont have permission to access the server you are trying to!. Check with any other url

Comment: Okay. Its a public website accessible on all browsers

Comment: Commonly a missing user-agent header.

Comment: Can you post the value of the variable 'website' ?